# How can this multiple integral be evaluated?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

I am stuck trying to solve the following integral:

$$\int_R (y+2x^2)(y-x^2) dA$$ where $R$ is defined by the following equations: $xy=1$, $xy=2$, $y=x^2$, $y=x^2-1$ with $x$ and $y$ positives.

I've tried several changes of variables for example: $u=xy$, $v=y-x^2$ or $u=y-x^2$, $v=x^2$ but I get stuck because for the Jacobian ot for the limits of integration I have to solve a third degree equation. I know that I could solve it using Cardano's formula but it has to be an easy way to do it.

Thank you very much.
Merry Christmas.

Comment: On behalf of @math15: It seems that there is an error in the integral. Are you sure that it is $(y+2x)$ and not $(y+2x^2)$ ?

Comment: Yes sorry, you are right!. I've already corrected it

Comment: The first idea, $u=xy$ and $v=y-x^2$, looks good with $\frac{\partial (u,v)}{\partial (x,y)}=y+2x^2$ and therefore $\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)}=\frac 1{y+2x^2}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've checked the inverse function theorem and yes, it works!

Answer (score 0):

As a first step it is better to represent the region of integration, as in the figure.

[image]

From this we see that, to integrate,  we have to divide the domain in three subregions as:

1) $ x_A\le x\le x_B$ where we have $\frac{1}{x}\le y\le x^2$

2) $ x_B\le x\le x_C$ where we have $\frac{1}{x}\le y\le \frac{2}{x}$

3) $ x_C\le x\le x_D$ where we have $x^2-1\le y\le \frac{2}{x}$

This gives us the limits of integration and the integration is simple for the given function. 
The problem is to find the coordinates of the points $A,B,C,D$ where we find some difficulty in solving equations of third degree.

Can you do from there?

Comment: Well, actually my problem is to compute C and D. I was told that there is a way to solve the integral without solving a third degree equation with a change of of variables but I cannot find one which avoid this problem.